# Getting a null pointer exception while calling getTimeStamp from firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The first time i run the app after uninstalling & reinstalling sometimes it crashes due to

```
 viewHolder.setTimestamp(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString((long) model.getTimestamp()).toString());
```

giving an error

```
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference
```

what should i do to solve this issue as after crashing once the next time everything works fine.If you need more codes to guide me then just ask.

Comment: `model.getTimestamp()` is returning null. You can't pass null to primitives or casting null to primitives.

Comment: explain a bit in details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score -2):

you can use it in try catch
like this way.

```
try
{
viewHolder.setTimestamp(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString((long) model.getTimestamp()).toString());
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```